# How to add a colon for Webform field labels?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, webforms, emails

I know you can add colon in field.tpl.php for site wide content type node fields, but looks like it's not webform field related.

And webform doesn't have any webform-field.tpl.php type of templates to edit?

By default, webform fields has no colons e.g. `Full Name` label needs to be `Full Name:`.

I know I can add that with CSS, e.g.

```
.form-item label:after {
  content: ":";
}
```

But this won't work because I need colons to be printed in subnmitted email template too.

And emails dont support `::after` `::before` CSS I think, or there is complication with various web email providers, etc.

I know you can add a manually `:` when creating the label name and like that for every field (but its tiring if multipage long forms), but that's impractical for various reasons like e.g. https://www.drupal.org/node/1922550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With D7 webforms, you should be able to access the parts of the webform (rendered within webform-form.tpl.php) within a form alter:

```
function mymodule_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {}
```

If you have the devel module enabled, you can use it to print out the variables within the $form['submitted'] array - for example, to edit the title of a form component, you would use:

```
$form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] = 'My new title';
```

To add a colon to the end of each component's attribute (i.e. to add a colon at the end of the #title attribute) you could set

```
$form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] = $form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] . ":";
```

If you use a variable instead of the specific 'my_form_component' name, you can set the form_alter function to loop over and add the ":" to the end of all component titles.

Small example here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1558246